# Change html input type colour only on mouse release in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, events, input, colors

```
<input className="color-palatte" type="color" onChange={(e) => onColorChange(e)} />
```

As I am using an API call on onChange() method, I don't want to call API when I slide over the colours and only call when I release it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but, I tackled the issue by using timeout on the api call. Basically, inside `onChange` you timeout the api call by a few milliseconds, and cancel the previous timeout. This way, your api only gets called if the user doesn't change the color before the current timeout.

Now the user can slide around the color selector without running a gazillion api calls.

Example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [apiTimeout, setApiTimeout] = useState(0); // <-- Stores timeout reference

    const apiCall = (color) => {
        // Your api call
    }

    return (
        <input
            type="color"
            onChange={e => {
                // In case timeout was already set, clear it
                clearTimeout(apiTimeout);

                // Set the next timeout
                setApiTimeout(
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    apiCall(e.target.value);
                  }, 300) // <-- Delay api call by 300 milliseconds. Set to what you prefer
                );
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onMouseUp`:

> onColorChange(e)} />

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event

**EDIT**

Ok, as far as I can see your problem is that the event is fired every time you adjust the colors in the popped-up modal with the color selector. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color), you can only use `onChange` and `onInput` events and both will fire after every color change. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to circumvent that.

Comment: It's not working the way it is intended. I even tried onMouseDown and onMouseMove. But they didn't help me either.

Comment: What does happen when you use `onMouseUp``Does it fire directly?

Comment: Yes, It got fired directly when I clicked the colour element and does not work after that.

Comment: Ok,so your problem is that with the first click, the color picker gets opened. But you don't want anything happen on that click. Then you push the mouse and slide over the color selection and the `onChange` handler fires. But it should only fire after you release the mouse button.

Comment: Yes, Do you have any solution for the same?